# What am I doing wrong in this Php coding?

Tags: php, arrays

Given a birthdate in the form mm/dd/yyyy, write a function that returns the person's age and true or false if today is the person's birthday.

For example, since today is 01/23/2015, your function would return the following:

getBirthDate('02/26/1975'); // returns array('age' => 39, 'birthday' => false);

getBirthDate('01/23/1994'); // returns array('age' => 21, 'birthday' => true);

This is what I have and I just cant seem to find out why the output wont come out like I need it to. When I run this code, no output is shown, but I can't figure out what I did wrong. What I want it to do is when it is run, it should output the age and true or false if that date is the person's birthday. But whenever I run this piece of code, the output is always blank or it just says Array. I would appreciate any help or suggestions to solving this! Thanks!

```
<?php
function getBirthDate($birthdate)
{

$agebirthday = array();


list($D, $M, $Y) = explode("/", $birthdate); 

$YearDifference = date("y") - $Y; 

if (date("m") == $M && (date("d") == $D)) 
{ 
$Birthday = true;
} 

else {
$Birthday = false;
}

array_push($agebirthday, array(
            "age" => $YearDifference,
        "birthday" => $Birthday));


return $agebirthday; 
} 


$output = getBirthDate($birthdate);
echo $output['age'];
echo $output['birthday'];




?>
```

Comment: Have you tried var_dump($output) after running the function to see the contents of the results?

Comment: I just tried to do the var_dump($output) and i got this as a result:
.
array (size=1)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'age' => int 15
      'birthday' => boolean false
.
Looking at this, how would I go about making the code out a array with these results?

Comment: @John Check my answer , you can not push arrays to array_push

Comment: Either CamelCase or all lowercase your variables. They are inconsistent.

Comment: Have you seen my answer? It has a complete solution with fixed dates calculations and some other minor fixes?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

in your code , change

```
array_push($agenbirthday, array(
            "age" => $YDiff,
        "birthday" => $Birthday));
```

to

```
$agenbirthday = array(
            "age" => $YDiff,
        "birthday" => $Birthday);
```

Comment: the very dates calculations were wrong, this answer isn't helping

Comment: Yes, but this is not an answer to the OP question. It doesn't solve the problem. This should be posted as a comment, not an answer

Comment: _“You can not push array in to array_push ,you can pass only values”_ – that’s nonsense; of course you can push an array into an array.

Comment: Thank you so much! This pretty much solved the problem that I was having. Yes I am aware that the date calculations are wrong, working on fixing that next. I just wanted it to output correctly first. Once again thanks so much Kanishka and all of you who replied!

Answer (score 0):

Here's my version, I've changed a few things:

```
function getBirthDate($birthdate)
{
    list($D, $M, $Y) = explode('/', $birthdate); 

    $YDiff = date('Y') - $Y;

    // the line below is optional, you may wish to count complete years age or not
    if(date("md") < $M.$D) $YDiff --;  // if it's BEFORE birthday

    return [
        "age" => $YDiff,
        "birthday" => date('md') == $M.$D
    ];
} 

$output = getBirthDate('28/05/1981');
var_dump($output['age']);
var_dump($output['birthday']);
```

Gives us the correct answer, for my birthday:

```
int(33)
bool(false)
```

Answer (score 0):

Make use of the strtotime() function. It converts dates to a large integer representing the number of seconds elapsed between the year 1970 and the date you specify, then subtract the value from the value of the time() function to get the number of seconds of time difference. Then use division on the result to get the desired number.

For example:

```
$seconds_old=time()-strtotime("02/26/1975");
```

Then you can do this:

```
$minutes_old=$seconds_old / 60;
$hours_old=$minutes_old / 60;
$days_old=$hours_old / 24;
$years_old=$days_old / 365;
```

And if the precision is too high, then research the intval() function.